# Passing kwargs into FactoryBoy nested RelatedFactories for pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, factory-boy

I see so many different ways of doing this that I'm getting a bit of choice paralysis.

**Problem description**

I have a top-level FactoryBoy factory, `FruitBasketFactory`. This defines a RelatedFactory to `AppleFactory`, a sort of "conduit" factory: `AppleFactory` defines 2 RelatedFactories: `SeedFactory` and `SkinFactory`. Some pseudo code:

```py
class FruitBasketFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = FruitBasket 

    apple = factory.RelatedFactory(
        AppleFactory,
        factory_related_name="fruit_basket"
    )
class AppleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Apple 
    
    fruit_basket = None
    
    seed = factory.RelatedFactory(
        SeedFactory,
        factory_related_name="apple"
    )
    skin = factory.RelatedFactory(
        SkinFactory,
        factory_related_name="apple"
    )

class SeedFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Seed 
    
    apple = None
    
    num_seeds = 10
    seed_color = "black"

class SkinFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Skin 
    
    apple = None
    
    skin_color="red"
```

**My goal**

For my tests, I want to set a top-level flag e.g. `fruit_basket_factory(apple_type_is_PinkLady=True)`, and 'pass down state' to all related, dependent factories. In this case, the changes required would be setting:

1. `fruit_basket.apple.seed.num_seeds = 5`
2. `fruit_basket.apple.seed.seed_color = "brown"`
3. `fruit_basket.apple.skin.skin_color= "green"`

Is this possible? I'm imagining some sort of `Class Params` on each Factory that serve as 'message-passers'?

In reality, my conduit factory has around 5-10 RelatedFactories.

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to use [`factory.Trait`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Trait):

```py
class FruitBasketFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Params:
    apple_type_is_pinklady = factory.Trait(
      apple__skin__skin_color="green",
      apple__seed__seed__color="brown",
      apple__seed__num_seeds=5,
    )
```

As a side note, why is `Seed` pointing to `Apple`, instead of the other way around? Can there be several seeds/skins on the same apple?

Comment: That's how I've currently set it, is there any way to condense all 3 of those traits into 1?

Re side note - I thought this setup meant "Create an Apple Factory, then create a Seed Factory, attaching to the `apple` attribute, which will be None by default." The setup is that one `Apple` can only have one `Seed`